# "outline-regexp" doesn't match headings that matches ";;;###autoload"

Tags: outline-mode

## The context

Consider this file `main.el`

```
;;; Heading no. 1

; This is not a heading
;; This is not a heading
;;;This is not a heading because there is no space after the the ";;;"

;;; Heading no. 2

; This is not a heading

;;;###autoload

; This is not a heading
```

In an fresh instance of Emacs (`emacs -Q`), the value of `outline-regexp` within buffers whose major mode is `emacs-lisp` is `";;;\\(;* [^  ]\\|###autoload\\)\\|("`. Therefore, the following lines are considered headings

- `;;; Heading no. 1`
- `;;; Heading no. 2`
- `;;;###autoload`

After executing `(outline-hide-sublevels 4)`, the content of the buffer is (yes, nothing is shown)

After executing `(outline-hide-sublevels 5)`, the content of the buffer is

```
;;; Heading no. 1
;;; Heading no. 2
```

Executing `outline-hide-sublevels` with an argument equal to 1, 2, 3, ..., 10 doesn't show the `;;;### autoload` heading.

## The question

Why is `outline-hide-sublevels` showing all the other headings except the `;;;### autoload` heading? Why isn't Emacs recognizing that line as a heading even though it matches the regular expression in `outline-regexp`?

Comment: I haven't played with levels much, but note that `C-h f outline-level` returns "either the level specified in `outline-heading-alist` or else the number of characters matched by `outline-regexp`." and the latter would be 14 for `;;;###autoload` by my reckoning.  On the very few occasions I've done custom things with levels, I've used the alist.